# react-native useEffect / useFocusEffect / useCallback not updating correctly

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am building a react-native app and seems I have a problem with the useFocusEffect ?
When the user opens the app, it displays a popup that prompts him to grant the write_settings_permission. As soon as the user returns back to the app screen, it should check if the permission was successfully granted and in that case navigate to a new screen, otherwise keep showing the popup.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, ActivityIndicator, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation, useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
import HotspotManager, {TetheringError} from '@react-native-tethering/hotspot';

const FirstScreen = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [showPermissionsPopup, setShowPermissionsPopup] = useState(false);
  const [permissionsGranted, setPermissionsGranted] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const requestWriteSettingsPermission = async () => {
    try {
      await HotspotManager.openWriteSettings();
      const granted = await HotspotManager.isWriteSettingsGranted();
      setPermissionsGranted(granted);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof TetheringError) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const checkPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await HotspotManager.isWriteSettingsGranted();
      console.log(
        `Write settings permission is ${granted ? 'granted' : 'not granted'}`,
      );
      setPermissionsGranted(granted);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof TetheringError) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      checkPermissions();
      console.log('test1');
    }, []),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setShowPermissionsPopup(true);
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (permissionsGranted) {
      console.log('test2');
      navigation.navigate('Network');
    }
  }, [navigation, permissionsGranted]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="blue" />
      ) : (
        <Text>Welcome to My App!</Text>
      )}

      {showPermissionsPopup && !permissionsGranted && (
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 20}}>
            <Text>Please grant the required permissions to continue.</Text>
            <Text
              style={{color: 'blue', textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}
              onPress={requestWriteSettingsPermission}>
              Grant Permissions
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default FirstScreen;
```

It works just fine, except the part that when I navigate back to the app from the settings, I have to press the "Grant the required Permissions" again, navigate to settings, go back to the app and only then it seems to work, at which point I am being redirected to the new screen.
What am I missing?

All I can think of is that the checkPermissions function is not being called when the user returns to the app because the focus effect hook is not triggered in that scenario, but I am failing to make it work even in that case.

I did find a somewhat similar error in the topics, but it didn't seem to have a solution as the creator of the question solved it himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I can think of is that the checkPermissions function is not being called when the user returns to the app because the focus effect hook is not triggered in that scenario, but I am failing to make it work even in that case.

You are right, you need to use `AppState` https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#useappstate

```js
// imports
import {useAppState} from '@react-native-community/hooks'


// start of the component
const currentAppState = useAppState()


// new code
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentAppState === 'active') {
    checkPermissions();
  }
}, [currentAppState]);
```

Comment: This was it!
I can't believe I never saw it in the API.
Thank you very much for the quick response and for the detailed explanation!
( I wish I could upvote your answer, but since I am a new user, it doesn't let me yet. I'll make sure I do once I reach the reputation needed to do so :)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the React.useCallback wrapper to see if that solves the problem.

```
useFocusEffect(() => {
  checkPermissions();
  console.log('test1');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, this doesn't solve it.